# Is shape of a black body much of a concern in physics?

Tags: blackbody, photon-emission, radiometry

When I read a book on computer vision, I stumble upon the ideal black body model. Using Lambert's cosine law ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_cosine_law)), one is able to compute the intensity of an area element dA w.r.t. some observer.

I didn't do the calculation myself, but I think it might be possible to have a closed form expression for the radiance of a spherical black body, such as the sun (although it is not Lambertian) from certain not so large distance such that the curvature of the black body is not negligible. From this, I'm wondering is there a general concern about the shape of black body in physics? If there is such a concern, any reference would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radiance of a body is the flux emitted by a surface per unit solid angle per unit projected area.

The flux from the surface of a blackbody in Watts per square metre per Hertz is given by $$F_{\nu} = \pi B_{\nu},$$
where $B_{\nu}$ is the Planck function.

The radiance of a blackbody surface is given by
$$\frac{1}{\pi} \int F_{\nu}\ d\nu\ = \frac{\sigma T^4}{\pi}$$

From [Wikipedia on the Stefan Boltzmann law.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law#Derivation_from_Planck.27s_law)

> Finally, this proof started out only considering a small flat surface. However, any differentiable surface can be approximated by a bunch of small flat surfaces. So long as the geometry of the surface does not cause the blackbody to reabsorb its own radiation, the total energy radiated is just the sum of the energies radiated by each surface; and the total surface area is just the sum of the areas of each surface—so this law holds for all convex blackbodies, too, so long as the surface has the same temperature throughout. The law extends to radiation from non-convex bodies by using the fact that the convex hull of a black body radiates as though it were itself a black body.

So I think the answer is no, the shape is not really a concern.

I think you could also use a symmetry argument. The total luminosity emerging from the Sun at any given frequency 
$$ L_{\nu} = 4\pi R^2 \pi B_{\nu},$$
where $R$ is the solar radius.

If you place a sphere of any radius around the Sun, then the total luminosity through this sphere must be the same.

So at the Earth at distance $d$ from the centre of the Sun:
$$ L_{\nu} = 4 \pi d^2 f_{\nu},$$
where $f_{\nu}$ is the flux per unit frequency received at Earth.

So 
$$f_{\nu} = \frac{R^2}{d^{2}} \pi B_{\nu}$$
and integrating over all frequencies (if you wish)
$$ f = \frac{R^2}{d^2} \sigma T^4 = \frac{L}{4\pi d^2}$$

Comment: brilliant answer. symmetry so elegant...but I guess $f_\nu$ is illuminance? Anyway, I already know what to do. Brilliant brilliant brilliant. you make me see the picture. I wish I had a physics teacher like you when I was younger.

Comment: Stumbled across this, very nice answer but the penultimate equation has  $R^{2}$ and $d^{2}$ the wrong way around.

Comment: You went over to photometric units. Not sure if that was intended.

Comment: @JanBos I don't understand your comment.  $f_{\nu}$ is a flux in W m$^{-2}$ Hz$^{-1}$. $f$ is an integrated flux in W m$^{-2}$ and $f = \int f_{\nu}\ d\nu$ etc. Ditto for $L$ but that is a luminosity in W.

Comment: @RobJeffries Luminous flux (lumen) is by all means equivalent to radiant flux (watt) but with some weigthing function in between related to human visual perception. It could be that I'm confused but I thought $R$ ~ $\sigma T^4$ would be valid only if all wavelenghts are included.

Comment: Who is talking about human perception? That is an irrelevant complication, and I have not addressed it @JanBos. Luminosity and flux are discussed here in SI units as used by astronomers.

Comment: @RobJeffries I thought you did by talking about Luminosity. Not a big deal. I understood that Luminosity is by definition associated with visible wavelengths (the spectral luminosity function) but apparently I'm wrong. Over the whole spectrum I thought terms like radiance (for luminance), radiant intensity etc are used.

Comment: Someone has down voted. Perhaps the answer could be improved?

Answer (score 1):

A black body simply refers to the property that a body's surface maximally interacts with thermal radiation (that is, it is not reflective). The shape does not matter. But the entire concept is a theoretical idealization. For practically useful results, you may need to incorporate the absorption spectrum of your body (simply multiply your black body result with it if you do your calculation spectrally resolved, or use the spectrally integrated albedo in its place if you do not).

In practice, when experimentalists intentionally want to approximate a black body, they will chose a shape that brings any body closer to a perfect black body: Use a small, deep hole, ideally opening into a big space. Then (almost) any reflection will be internal, such that the interaction through the hole will be like that of a surface with many more than one chance to absorb or emit a photon. This could be the source of misunderstandings about whether some shape is implied in the term "black body" since a certain kind of people will naturally associate the term with such intentionally good approximations through shaping.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I read through wikipedia and found similar explanation. Now that the shape is out of the window, can you show me how to compute sun's spectral irradiance at TOA using Plank's equation? I guess I should compute the solid angle of earth w.r.t. sun. And also if we want to compute the radiant flux, what should be the area of the sun as a black body?

Comment: No, but I'm sure you should be able to show yourself. To make it easy on you, consider using the [Stefan Boltzmann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law) law rather than rederiving everything ab initio. The surface area of the sun is, to a rather good approximation, the surface area of a sphere (its [photosphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosphere), really). What is TOA?

Comment: top of atmosphere. Thanks, but still not sure why I should use Stefan-Bolzmann...a little confused here, I wanted to have spectral...

Comment: You don't have to use it; that was just a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks pyramids. I'd hope you recommend me a reference for serious college physics, that I'd take my time to self-study. I heard that Feynmann is not really suitable for newbies...

Comment: Sorry pyramids, Rob just sees through my mind and made the more satisfying answer.